# Coroutines: Overriding OKHttp's dispatcher to use AsyncTasks's ThreadPoolExecutor so Espresso can assert successfully

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-espresso, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines

I am migrating an app that uses `Retrofit` to work with coroutines. The app has some UATs that are failing because Espresso does not wait for the coroutines to complete and asserts immediately.

The `CoroutineCallAdapterFactory`, by default, uses OkHttp's `Dispatcher` to perform asynchronous requests, but `Espresso` only monitors the UI `Thread` and `AsyncTaks`'s `Thread` pool. One solution I thought of is to force `OkHttp`'s Dispatcher to use `AsyncTask`'s `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
val dispatcher = Dispatcher(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR as ExecutorService)
okHttpClientBuilder.dispatcher(dispatcher)
```

This seems to work and the tests pass.

Is this a bad idea? Is registering an `IdlingResource` still a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details of your setup, I'm not sure if this information will help but I'll mention a few tips that may help with your tests:

### Convert Executors

You can also go the other way and create a coroutine dispatcher from any executor using:

```
AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

And of course, this can be used anyplace you'd have something like `Dispatchers.Main` meaning you can create a scope from this and launch your coroutines from that scope and Espresso should monitor the underlying executor pool for completion. For example:

```
...
val espressoScope = CoroutineScope(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.asCoroutineDispatcher())
...
espressoScope.launch { api.getBooks() }
```

Similarly, you can do things like:

```
val asyncTaskContext = AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.asCoroutineDispatcher()
withContext(asyncTaskContext) {
    api.getBooks()
}

// OR:

@Test
fun someAndroidTest() = runBlocking(asyncTaskContext) {
    // espresso logic
}
```

### Join Jobs (recommended)

Last but not least, you can join any jobs that you create in your test and the test will wait until the job completes before exiting. This sounds like the approach that would help most in your situation since you really just want to wait until the coroutines are complete:

```
@Test
fun `first book has a title`() = runBlocking {
    launch {
        // run a function that suspends and takes a while
        val firstBook = api.getAllBooks().first()
        assertNotNull(firstBook.title)
    }.join()
}
```

Comment: So it is ok to use the AsyncTask Thread pool? I know that coroutine Dispatchers are optimized for the task at hand (i.e. Dispatcher.IO is optimized for IO tasks) and I do not know if AsyncTask's Thread pool is as optimized.

Comment: I thought `AsyncTask` api was deprecated by Google?